# Why formic acid is stronger than benzoic acid? Don't explain through pKa values

Tags: organic-chemistry

Acidity in organic compunds, specially carboxylic acids.

Answer (score 2):

One possible explanation:  solvation.  Formate ion is compact with essentially no hydrocarbon component, and so is more strongly solvated by water solvent than other carboxylate ions.  One could say the same about neutral formic acid versus other carboxylic acids, but solvation effects are stronger for ions than for neutral molecules.  So the favorable solvation for formic acid/formate tends to promote formation of the ion making the acid stronger.

Comment: Good explanation, but doesn't this only hold in the cases where the acid is aqueous?